# is there a dired-like mode that behaves like XEmacs' dired

Tags: dired, xemacs

Having mostly switched to Emacs, I still sorely miss the `dired` mode of XEmacs.

As far as I can tell, XEmacs' `dired` started from `dired-x` (not Emacs' `dired`) many years ago and then drifted away, so I guess that `dired-x` (that now has drifted away from the `dired-x` of many years ago as well) plus a number of extra packages and/or customizations may eventually lead to a partially satisfactory solution.

I hope that (a part of) all this hassle can be avoided using some ready-made fix, so my question is,

> is there a port of the Xemacs' `dired`, or at least a partial port, for Emacs 24.x?

Tia

PS: my question, despite the previous title that was a little misleading, does not concern customizing specific aspects of `dired` but is about a ready-made mode that mimics XEmacs' `dired`.  In this respect I don't feel like giving a detailed list of differences between the implementations, at least for now --- I may change my mind if no answers will show up...

Comment: Can you please add explanation and screenshots of what's "XEmacs dired" is to your question?

Comment: I have edited my question (and its title) to clarify my point of view on the problem. I have to say that, for the while, I don't think a list of differences may help with my question. Thank you for showing me one of the defects of my question,

Comment: Even with the edit you made, I do not think any potential helper can help you if they do not know what "behaves like XEmacs dired" means. It is important for a question poster to put in some effort to formulate a good question. Check out `M-x dired` in GNU Emacs, have a read of this feature in this manual, and then you can report back on the features it's missing compared to the XEmacs dired version.

Comment: Well other ex-XEmacs users are "potential helpers" who may very well not need any additional information. I presume that is what gboffi is counting on (as everyone else is likely to ignore this question).

Comment: The question is unclear and too broad. If you ask about how to emulate a specific feature from XEmacs Dired, you might get some help. Otherwise, I doubt it. Of course, you can still use XEmacs.

Comment: @phils Exactly so.

Comment: Please provide a link to the most recent version of dired for Xemacs so that we can all see the differences with our own eyes, and maybe someone will be motivated to patch it up so that it works with the current version of regular/vanilla Emacs.

Comment: I don't feel the need to enumerate all the small, none of them a show-stopper, anti-enhancements (lots of smilies)  that I'm facing because given sufficient time and motivation I can do everything I need on my own, resorting to ESE  for the pieces that eventually don't fit — I just need to know, before starting this effort, if said effort has already been accomplished. As [phils](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/454/phils) underlined, it is possible that a sub-class of ESE users could help anyway. OTOH, if I will receive no answers, it means NO, and I will start tinkering my `,emacs`

Comment: @lawlist ftp://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/xemacs/beta/experimental/packages/dired-1.22-pkg.tar.gz  contains the latest distributed sources. I don't know if the latest unreleased branch is still available somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the answer is `no`.

You'll be better off asking for the specific features/behaviors you miss.

Comment: Thank you Stefan, I will start on my own and come back to ESE when in trouble.

Comment: @gboffi: It'd be nice if you do it in a separate file which you can then distribute as something like `xemacs-dired.el`, so that you end up making my answer invalid.

Comment: I will try.  If I'll get something even vaguely useful I'm going to post an answer to my own question.  Thank you for trying to motivate me, it's tough stuff but you made a nice attempt!